# Write float values to Pointer Array of float in C# (unsafe or safe) using AVAudioPCMBuffer

Tags: ios, .net, c#-4.0, mono, xamarin.ios

While I'm not very comfortable using the unsafe context in C#, I do understand that I may have to sometimes use it.

To get right to it, in order to write byte values to an **IntPtr**, I could write the below from a safe context:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) 
{
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteByte (data, i, 0);
}
```

How can i do the same from an unsafe context?

To be more specific I am actually trying to write float values to a an Intptr variable that is actually a float array pointer. I dont see any overloads capable of handling writing float data using **System.Runtime.InteropServices** from a safe context.

I tried the below but get the error:

malloc: *** error for object 0x17e9eca4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

```
var data = (float*)buffer.FloatChannelData;

for (int i = 0; i < buffer.FrameLength; i++) 
{
    data [i] = 0.0f;
    *data++ = 0.0f; // also tried this but got the same error
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

**Additional details:**

I am trying to write data to AudioPCMBuffers in Xamarin.IOS. I thought the buffer contained a an array of float but as pointed by @Passant in the comments it actually contains an array of pointers to array of framelength floats. he same premise applies, whether from a safe or unsafe context I would like to be able to write data to the buffers. An example will be very helpful. Thanks and apologies for the confusion

Comment: For the record, I've been working with C# for over a decade and I've never needed to work with `unsafe` blocks.

Comment: @Mann i am happy to work in a safe context as well. Any recommendations as to how I can solve my problem in a safe context? ie write float values to a float array pointer

Comment: Smells like an AVAudioPCMBuffer, I wonder why we have to guess at it.  Which is not an array of float, it is an array of pointers (channelCount of them) to arrays of frameLength floats.  So if that is accurate then you indeed corrupt the bejeezus out of memory.

Comment: @Passant you're absolutely right about this being an AVAudioPCMBuffer. It was never my intention to have you guess anything. On the contrary I was trying to narrow down the problem as best I could in order to Make the question very specific. I will edit the question to include this detail. Feel free to provide a solution on how to access the array of pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rolf's](https://stackexchange.com/users/61573/rolf-bjarne-kvinge) answer for the question is here:

> Try this: https://gist.github.com/rolfbjarne/dc947383a6c9172bc664
>
> It will mix mic input with a sine wave.